# ReviewBoard with git. "There don't seem to be any diffs!" but there are

Tags: git, review-board

I'm trying this codereview tool. I'm having problems with git.
This is the output of `git status`:

```
# On branch master
# Changes not staged for commit:
#   (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
#   (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
#
#   modified:   path/to/something/modified.js
#
# Untracked files:
#   (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
#
#   .gitignore
#   .reviewboardrc
```

If i try to run `post-review --guess-summary --guess-description -p` under this status I get this message:

> There don't seem to be any diffs!

Now, if I run `git add -u`, my `git status` is:

```
# On branch master
# Changes to be committed:
#   (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)
#
#   modified:   path/to/something/modified.js
#
# Untracked files:
#   (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
#
#   .gitignore
#   .reviewboardrc
```

With this situation, if I run again `post-review --guess-summary --guess-description -p` I still get the same message:

> There don't seem to be any diffs!

At this point if I commit it with the command `git commit -m "my commit"` I have the following message (obviously):

> [master 027e044] my commit  1 file changed, 1 insertion(+)

and I run again the post-review command I have the output:

```
Review request #22 posted.

http://192.168.133.218/r/22/
```

This puzzles me because If you go to read the ReviewBoard FAQ here's the message:

> A basic pre-commit workflow with git would look like this:
>
> ```
> Clone the central repository.
> Make a change you want reviewed, but do not commit it yet.
> Run post-review (or otherwise submit a diff).
> Get reviews, update your change as needed.
> When the change is marked to ship, commit it to master and push it to the origin.
> ```

Since my intention was doing a pre-commit, can you explain to me why there are no diff after I stage changes for commit?